# Apply numpy function (np.vstack) on generator returning 2 values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, generator

I have a generator function that returns batches of x and y data. Now I want to write a function that exhausts the generator and stacks it, so that I have my whole input and output of my database in 2 numpy arrays.

If the generator would have been separated, the following code would work:

```
import numpy as np
import time

def foo_gen_x(epochs):
  for _ in range(epochs):
    yield np.array([1, 2])

def foo_gen_y(epochs):
  for _ in range(epochs):
    yield np.array(["foo"])

start = time.time()
x_epoch = np.vstack(foo_gen_x(100000))
y_epoch = np.vstack(foo_gen_y(100000))
print(x_epoch)
print(y_epoch)
# output x_epoch
# [[1 2]
# ...
# [1 2]]
# output y_epoch
# [['foo']
# ...
# ['foo']]
print("time taken: {}".format(time.time() - start))
# time taken: time taken: 0.6881139278411865
```

However, the generator I have looks more like this (returning 2 values):

```
def foo_gen_xy(epochs):
  for _ in range(epochs):
    yield np.array([1, 2]), np.array(["foo"])
```

## Attempt 1

So I tried to write something like this:

```
x_epoch, y_epoch = [np.vstack(x), np.vstack(y) for x, y in foo_gen_xy(epochs=4)]
# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

But that gives a `ValueError`.

## Attempt 2

Then I tried a more explicit approach:

```
# working but too many lines (and slower?)
start = time.time()
gen = foo_gen_xy(100000)
x_epoch, y_epoch = gen.__next__()

for x, y in gen:
    x_epoch = np.vstack((x_epoch, x))
    y_epoch = np.vstack((y_epoch, y))

print(x_epoch)
print(y_epoch)
print("time taken: {}".format(time.time() - start))
# time taken: 31.917259454727173
```

This is about 46x slower.

## Attempt 3

I could first just stack everything with:

```
epoch = np.vstack(foo_gen_xy(100000))
# output
# [[array([1, 2]) array(['foo'], dtype='<U3')]
# ...
# [array([1, 2]) array(['foo'], dtype='<U3')]]
```

However, splitting that up seems like a roundabout way and it introduces another issue that the `dtype` changes.

## Code in a Jupyter Notebook

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IncrTAosFuQmK65ojmzWV38F8FceL3qt

## Question

What would be a more efficient way of applying `np.vstack()` on a generator function that returns 2 values?

Comment: try returing the tuple from the generator function ? and also i think to vertically stack the arrays we need the same dtypes ?

Comment: try: np.vstack (*next (generator))

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain `yield x, y` is the same as `yield (x, y)`.  I've added sample output to the first code snippet. `np.vstack()` should indeed stack the same dtype (`[1, 2]` on `[1, 2]`). Attempt 3 is therefore not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution and timing

Here's a simple, fast one liner:

```
arrs = [np.vstack(a) for a in zip(*foo_gen_xy(10000))]
#78 ms ± 48.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Output:

```
[array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       ...,
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2]]), array([['foo'],
       ['foo'],
       ['foo'],
       ...,
       ['foo'],
       ['foo'],
       ['foo']], dtype='<U3')]
```

## Note about initializing a big array from many subarrays

This kind of complex array initialization from a large list of subarrays (and the associated timings) have been discussed to death on SO many times before. Here's the short version:

- Generating a single Python `list` of your arrays and then concatenating (or stacking, or whatever) all of them all at once is usually at least as fast as any fancier, more optimized-seeming solution
- The other reliably fast method is to preinitialize one large output array (or in your case, two large output arrays) and then populate that in a loop. For large enough subarrays, the performance of these two methods is typically equivalent.

## Note about your first attempt

To fix the `ValueError` that you're getting from the code in your first attempt, just wrap the list elements in a tuple:

```
x_epoch, y_epoch = [(np.vstack(x), np.vstack(y)) for x, y in foo_gen_xy(epochs=4)]
```

In list comprehensions, each "loop" has to return exactly one value, so the standard way to work around this limitation is to instead return exactly one `tuple`. This still won't give you the result you want, since it doesn't actually join any arrays together.

Comment: Your one liner works, thank you! The first attempt was to show how I was thinking, and I also tried the tupple approach, but that indeed didn't give me what I wanted.